# Showing that $|u|$ is absolutely continuous for $u \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$

Tags: real-analysis, weak-derivatives

Suppose that we have  $u \in C^1(\Omega)$, for an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to show that $|u|$ is differentiable almost everywhere. I intuitively understand that this is true, but I need to prove it.

I need it to use the fundamental theorem of calculus of Lebesgue for the partial derivatives of $|u|$.

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Since $u$ is continuous you can decompose $\Omega$ into two areas where $u$ is positive, negative respectively. On both areas -- obviously -- the function is weak differentiable, because there is no absolute value involved. So you just have to verify that the integration by parts formula holds if you integrate over the set where $u$ changes its sign... you also could state that $u$ in Lipschitz, so $u\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ and in particular in $W^{1,1}$ meaning it is absolutely continuous if $\Omega$ is bounded.

Comment: @Alex Can we conclude that the set where $u$ changes sign is of measure $0$?

Answer (score 0):

$A=${$\Omega$: $u >0$}

$B=${$\Omega$: $u \le 0$}

since $f$ is continuous, $A$ is actually a countable union of disjoint intervals and a finite number of points,$B$ is also a countable union of intervals and a finite number of points. $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

So You can use absolute continuity and differentiabilty on the intervals of $A$ and $B$ separately. The finite number of points have measure zero.